# Neovim COC - "node is not executable"

Tags: coc.nvim

(I am using ubuntu 18.04 WSL2 on the Windows 10 terminal emulator)

Hello, i am having problems with coc on Neovim. The coc plugin is installed correctly (with vim-plug), but when i started nvim a massege would appear **"node is not executable"**, so, i changed the path in the **init.vim** folder, **"let g:coc_node_path = 'C:/nodejs/node.exe'"**, but now another erro message appears **" "C>/nodejs/node.exe" is not executable "**, does someone know how to fix that?

My **"init.vim"** file and **"plug-config"** folder: https://github.com/user-d4ba/Files

Comment: Is installing node inside the WSL an option for you? At least that's how I am doing it and it works without any problems

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone has my situation. I had node installed with node nvm/npm. The error never happened when I started nvim from the command line, only from the Application Menu (in KDE).

I got node's path with:

```
$ nvm which current
```

Then in init.nvm which was in ~/.config/nvim:

```
let g:coc_node_path = 'path'
```

Answer (score 2):

You may not have installed node. Check to make sure you have - if you haven't, you can find install instructions and binaries on [their GitHub](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall), or use an applicable package manager if you prefer.

You can also reinstall it if you are not sure.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28853092)

Comment: @gehbiszumeis This isn't a link-only answer